# »Er schläft noch schlummert nicht«

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunction, style

Im Oratorium *Elias* von Felix Mendelssohn Bartholdy kommt im Satz 29 (Der Hüter Israels) dieser Satz vor:

> Siehe, der Hüter Israels schläft noch schlummert nicht.

Diese Textstelle ist der Bibel entnommen (Psalm 121, Vers 4), und lautet in verschiedenen Übersetzungen der Bibel jeweils unterschiedlich, nämlich unter anderem:

- > Siehe, der Hüter Israels schläft und schlummert nicht. (Lutherbibel 1984)
- > Siehe, nicht schlummert und nicht schläft der Hüter Israels. (Elberfelder Bibel)
- > Ja, der Beschützer Israels schläft und schlummert nicht. (Hoffnung für alle)
- > Nein, der Hüter Israels schläft und schlummert nicht. (Einheitsübersetzung)

Mir geht es um die Version in Mendelssohns Elias (»[Er] schläft noch schlummert nicht«): Klingt der Satz für moderne Ohren einfach nur ungewohnt, obwohl er auch nach modernen Maßstäben grammatisch richtig ist, oder ist das ein Satz, den ein Lehrer im Jahr 2016 in einem Schulaufsatz als falsch ankreiden würde? Wenn ja: Was genau ist falsch?

Comment: Eine Möglichkeit, die der Lehrer hätte, wäre, ein fehlendes Komma zwischen *noch* und *schlummert* einzufügen, das würde aber die Bedeutung definitiv verschieben. Interessante Frage!

Comment: Klar, daraus einen Satz mit einer anderen Bedeutung zu machen wäre natürlich eine Möglichkeit, aber die Aussage soll bleiben: Er ist hellwach.

Comment: Übrigens: Die Fassung "_der Hüter Israels schläft noch schlummert nicht._" fand sich noch in der [Lutherbibel von 1912](http://www.bibel-online.net/buch/luther_1912/psalm/121/#1). Die [Fassung von 1545](http://www.bibel-online.net/buch/luther_1545_letzte_hand/psalm/121/#1) lautete:  "_Sihe / der Hüter Jsrael / Schlefft noch schlumet nicht_."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beim Vergleich mit der Version aus der 1984er Lutherbibel wird klar, dass *noch* in diesem Satz wie eine Konjunktion gebraucht wird. Wie wir [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=13,872,61) entnehmen können, war die Konjunktion *noch* tatsächlich früher in weitaus mehr Varianten im Gebrauch als heute.

Speziell zu der hier angefragten Konstellation schreiben sie in Abschnitt 3aβ:

> noch *vor nachfolgender, zur verstärkung dienender negation war namentlich im 16. jh. beliebt, ist aber nun wie überhaupt die doppelte negation nicht mehr gebräuchlich:* die lilien des ackers .. arbeiten noch spinnen nit. *bibel von* 1483 472b (sie erbeiten nicht, auch spinnen sie nicht. *Matth. 6, 28);*

D.h. dieser Satzbau war zu Luthers Zeiten gebräuchlich und diente der Verstärkung des zweiten Satzteils; aber schon zu Zeiten der Brüder Grimm galt er als veraltet.

Zum heutigen Gebrauch der Konjunktion *noch* schreibt der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noch_und_auch_nicht):

> schließt in Korrelation mit einer Negation ein zweites Glied [und weitere Glieder] einer Aufzählung an; und auch nicht

Auch wenn es nicht ganz eindeutig formuliert ist, würde ich es doch eher so interpretieren, dass die erwähnte Negation im ersten Satzteil stehen muss; Luthers Satzbau wäre nach diesem Maßstab "falsch" (weil: "falscher"/unüblicher Gebrauch einer Konjunktion - ein guter Deutschlehrer würde dazu aber vielleicht eher einen Hinweis als einen Fehler notieren). Insbesondere, weil dies in beiden Beispielen der Fall ist, die der Duden gibt: Zum einen die mehrteilige Form *weder ... noch*, die wir als alltäglich empfinden, zum anderen die als "gehoben" markierte Variante

> sie hat keine Verwandten/nicht Verwandte noch Freunde

Das Bibelzitat könnte man also, wenn man *noch* nach Duden "korrekt" verwenden möchte, so formulieren:

> Siehe, der Hüter Israels schläft nicht noch schlummert er.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deinen interessanten Beitrag. Könntest du eventuell auch noch meine Frage beantworten? Ist der Satz nach modernen Regeln korrekt? Wenn nicht: Warum nicht?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Da ich den Schul-Irrsinn seit einigen Jahrzehnten hinter mir habe, sehe ich Korrektheitsfragen zur deutschen Sprache, wenn sie über Zeichensetzung und Groß-/Kleinschreibung hinausgehen, eher als ein _ill-posed problem_. In diesem Sinne fand ich die Antwort auch bisher schon als hinreichend konkret. Ich hab sie aber trotzdem nochmal überarbeitet.

Comment: Bin auch bei dir, dass die *nicht...noch* -Reihenfolge für unser modernes Sprachverständnis einfach "falschrum" ist. Wir erwarten einfach, dass die Negation zuerst kommt. Selbst die Version in der "richtigen" Reihenfolge dürfte (abgesehen vom "weder...noch" ziemlich ungebräuchlich sein.

Answer (score 1):

Dies ist zwar keine vollständige Antwort, aber ich möchte dennoch zu Matthias' exzellenter Antwort etwas hinzufügen.

Der Satz

> Siehe, der Hüter Israels **nicht** schläft **noch** schlummert.

ist auch heute noch richtig, obgleich die Wendung <nicht … noch> als veraltend gilt (siehe das Stichwort [„noch“ im DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/noch#2)). Daher reduziert sich die Frage, ob der Satz

> Siehe, der Hüter Israels schläft **noch** schlummert **nicht**.

auch nach modernen Maßstäben grammatisch richtig sei, auf die Frage, ob der Positionswechsel des Wortes *nicht* an das Satzende zulässig ist.